# Statistical tests in AB testing

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, ab-test

I'm using AB test calculator (http://abtestguide.com/calc/) and I'm wondering what statistical test is lying under it. Is it t-test or z-test?

Comment: Have you tried asking the creator?

Comment: The compuattions are pretty much self-explanatory. (And to answer your question they use a Z-test)